# Are questions about ideas for projects on or off topic?

Tags: discussion

I'd like to get tips about electronics projects with the theme of Christmas. Is this question on or off topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Chiphacker, it was definitely on topic. We had a large number of opinionated questions, skim https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=best+kit for a sampling.  However, as I understand it, the Trilogy sites are much less tolerant of these kinds of questions, so we may have to adjust our policies a little.

What do people from the Trilogy sites think: Should the linked questions be discouraged?

**EDIT**: Also, you didn't ask a question.  You proposed a subject.  For example,

> ### What are some good projects to give to beginners?
>
> Question same as title.

Will be (rightly) poorly received, while [one that is asked well](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3641/good-easy-soldering-projects-like-bristlebots), with good details, an example solution, and ideas for a start on the answer will be well received.

Perhaps you can give an example of the question you would ask about a project for Christmas?

Comment: This kind of question is tolerable in inverse proportion to the number of users.

Comment: @joe - Interesting note.  I was wondering why SO was so critical of this type of question, and that thought explains it.

Answer (score 2):

As a Chiphacker user who has suddenly found himself a user of the Electronics and Robotics Stack Exchange site without so much as a by your leave, I vote we continue with our existing standards from Chiphacker until someone tells us we can't. Are we not a major section of the user base of this site after all?

Comment: I agree, I think this new site should largely adopt the standards and practises of chiphacker, but as I'm not a former chiphacker user myself, I'm not really sure what those existing standards are. Perhaps a series of questions and answers here on the meta site should establish that for the newer users.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how that could be considered off-topic.  It's part of "robotics, electronics, physical computing, and even those working with an Arduino", no?